# How can Python consume a quoted argument from a shell variable?

Tags: shell-script, shell, python

I am trying to parametrize a call to pytest like this:

```
export OPTIONS="tests -k 'not e2e'"
pytest ${OPTIONS}
```

The `pytest` call fails because of the quotes in the variable. Putting the options directly in the call works fine.

I tried:

```
pytest ${OPTIONS} 
ERROR: file not found: tests -k 'not e2e'

pytest $(eval echo "${OPTIONS}") # removes all quotes
ERROR: file not found: e2e

pytest $(printf %s ${OPTIONS})
```

How can I make the `pytest` call work in a parametrized way?

**UPDATE**

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949/376813) contains a solution that works:

```
eval "OPTIONS=($OPTIONS)" # (opt.) convert an existing string to an array

export OPTIONS=(tests -k 'not e2e')
pytest "${OPTIONS[@]}"
```

Thank you very much for pointing that out. I was already searching for hours.

Comment: Note: the linked duplicate is about storing commands in a variable but the top answer also details storing command options in an array, as well as several other solutions that would also work for this issue.

Comment: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373) has the whole command in the variable vs. here it's just the arguments. It doesn't matter though, the issue is how the variable expands, having a fixed command name (or some other fixed arguments around it) doesn't change that. (the shell doesn't really process the command name any differently from the other arguments.)

Comment: How could this work in a sh or ash environment which do not support arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Has you tried this?

```
export OPTIONS="tests -k \'not e2e\'"
```

It must work with `eval`

Comment: I tried and unfortunately, it fails with `ERROR: file not found: e2e\'`